# Weird notation for function

Tags: integration, functions, notation

I was going through my textbook today and I found this question which defined a function $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=\int_0^{x}\sin{(\lfloor{2x}\rfloor)}dx$$

and was asking to calculate $f(\frac{\pi}{2})$.

I get that the question wants me to evaluate,

$$f(x)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{(\lfloor{2x}\rfloor)}dx$$

But this notation is bothering me because of the $x$ inside the integral. Shouldn't the proper notation be, $$f(x)=\int_0^{x}\sin{(\lfloor{2t}\rfloor)}dt$$

Am I wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are right, the statement you reproduce has an abuse of notation.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, and so we'd have
$$
f(\pi/2) = \int_0^{\pi/2} = \sin(\lfloor 2t\rfloor)\ \mathsf dt = \frac{1}{2} (\sin (1)+\sin (2)+\pi  \sin (3)-3 \sin (3)).
$$

Comment: The only ambiguity is whether the $x$ in $\lfloor 2x\rfloor$ is the variable of integration or the argument of $f$; all of the other occurrences of $x$ are completely well-defined. And I would say it is "clear" that this $x$ is meant to be the variable of integration (though, as I said in agreement with @ClementC. , it is poor notation).